# Node command not returned output with passing multiple parameter using .NET Core

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core-mvc

I am executing one node command which accepts more than two arguments in .NET Core 8 environment. But I get a blank output.

Below is the node command which I used in PowerShell window and get the output:

```
node rsa-sign.js ./privatekey.pem <Unique identity number>
```

In the above command, node runs this `rsa-sign.js` file and takes private key from a `.pem` file with unique identity number and generate some signature in the PowerShell window.

Same thing I am trying to achieve in .NET Core as well.

To get that, this is what I have tried so far:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GenerateSignature(string fPath, string identity)
{
    string _rsaFilePath = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\js\", "rsa-sign.js");
    string nodeCommand = _rsaFilePath; // Node.js script name or path
    string privateKeyPath = fPath;
    string inputValue = identity;

    string output = ExecuteNodeCommand(nodeCommand, $"{privateKeyPath} {inputValue}");

    return Json(output);
}

private string ExecuteNodeCommand(string scriptName, string arguments)
{
    try
    {
        //string scriptOutput = ExecuteNodeCommand(nodeCommand, $"{privateKeyPath} {inputValue}");
    
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "node",
            Arguments = $"{scriptName} {arguments}",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (Process process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            process.WaitForExit();

            return output.Trim();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error executing Node.js command: {ex.Message}");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But when I check the output variable, it is blank only.

I need your help, please.

Comment: And you are sure, the command executes sucessfully, ie doesn't throw an exception?

Comment: Yes, I put the breakpoint in string output = line and found like it is executing till there. Before it i checked command to verify the node version and used "-v" in argument and got the node version in same output line.

Comment: You have two `string output = ...` which one do you mean? But your code looks fine, and the fact that you get output when running `node -v` confirms, that it works. So it seems the problem is either in your script or in the way you pass the parameters. I don't know your script, so it may as well not create any output on invalid parameters. But that won't cause the c# to throw an exception. It may not even return an `process.ExitCode` different from `0`.  Add some debug output to your node script (be sure to create some output at the very beginning of it) and check if you receive it ...

Answer (score 0):

In the above one i did mistake with private key file, Like when i was uploading this file then i used CreateOrAppend. In that case Every upload of file it was appending the private key data in same file. Due to that private key was getting broken. So now to fix this, Now everytime when user upload new private key file, I check and delete old file and upload new file there. Now my node command is working as expected. Thank you everyone, Who supported me.